# How to resolve ValueError: The circuit contains non-deterministic observables

Tags: stim

I constructed a part of the syndrome measurement circuit as follows using Stim. However, when I run `dem = circuit.detector_error_model()` and `print(repr(dem))`, I get the error message `ValueError: The circuit contains non-deterministic observables.` Why is that happening? What I want to achieve is that at the end of this circuit, if an odd number of qubits (0 to 16) have experienced Z errors, the logical observable  flips, enabling the detection of Z errors.

Answer (score 1):

Having non-deterministic observables or detectors is one of the most common and difficult errors you will encounter when using Stim. I call it difficult because it's a mistake in your circuit but there's a huge variety of mistakes that it could be. Debugging that kind of variety can be hard. It could be:

- A measurement record target being off by one
- A missing CNOT
- A missing or additional or wrong qubit rotation
- A reset in the wrong basis
- An extra measurement
- A `DETECTOR` that should not have been there in the first place (e.g. asserting X basis stabilizers are deterministic in the first round when initializing in the Z basis)
- And on and on and on

There are a variety of strategies I use to debug these issues:

- Read the rest of the error message closely. It will say *what* anticommuted, *where* it anticommuted, and *when* it anticommuted. All of these are useful hints.
- See how much of the end of the circuit you can cut off. If `circuit[:20].detector_error_model()` fails, you know there's a problem in the first 20 instructions.
- Make a `stim.Circuit.diagram` of the circuit and check that things look right.
- Put the circuit into an interactive editor like crumble, that lets you track how Paulis propagate. Recreate the detector or observable in question and check it moves how you expect.
- Build up circuit generation tools that make it harder to make these mistakes in the first place. For example, something that tracks the measurement indices for you and lets you refer to them by more human-convenient names while building the circuit.

In your specific circuit you could have caught the problem by reading the rest of the error message more closely:

```
ValueError: The circuit contains non-deterministic observables.
(Error analysis requires deterministic observables.)

This was discovered while analyzing qubit initialization into |0> at the start of the circuit on:
    qubit 0

The collapse anti-commuted with these detectors/observables:
    L0
    L1

[...]
```

The fact that L0 and L1 both anticommuted was the hint. Why is there an L0 and an L1? There should only be one observable here.

You said `OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(1)` at the end of the circuit but `OBSERVABLE_INCLUDE(0)` at the start of the circuit, so you've declared two separate observables instead of combining an observable's initial measurement and its final measurement to form a comparison.